# Susy Error: WARNING: Static math requires a valid column-width setting

Tags: susy-sass, susy

I continue to get this error in my terminal.

**Error: WARNING: Static math requires a valid column-width setting**

I am currently using gulp and gulp-sass for my app. This is my main.scss file, and I can't seem to figure out how to satisfy this error. The actual error brings up nothing in Google, and I have followed Susy's docs. Susy also states that I don't need Compass, so I haven't installed gulp-compass.

**main.scss**

```
@import "susy";

$susy: (
  columns: 12,
  gutters: 1/4,
  math: fluid,
  output: float,
  container: 1140px,
  gutter-position: inside,
);

#main {
  @include container;
}
```

**gulpfile.js**

```
gulp.task('css', function () {
  gulp.src('./src/scss/main.scss')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass({
      errLogToConsole: true,
      sourceComment: 'normal'
    } ))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});
```

Comment: I can't recreate the error based on what you have here. Susy and Gulp-sass only work together in the very latest releases (Susy 2.2.0.beta.2+ and gulp-sass 1.2.4+) — but you should only see this error if you try using static math (you don't in your sample).

Comment: @EricMSuzanne That makes sense then, because I am using Susy 2.1. I assume I should download the libsass branch?

Comment: Yep, hopefully that does it.